# Docker build error on Visual Studio for Mac - No build stage in current context

Tags: node.js, macos, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

I am having a problem with building a ASP.NET CORE app with Angular and Node.js on my Mac using Docker and Visual Studio.

This is the current Error:

```
> /Applications/Visual
> Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/build/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(5,5):
> Error: Building fjord.karve.experiment.server No build stage in current
> context.
> 
> For more troubleshooting information, go to
> http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting (docker-compose)
```

Here is my current Docker File Attempt:

```
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Fjord.sln ./
COPY fjord.karve.experiment.server/fjord.karve.experiment.server/Fjord.Karve.Experiment.Server.csproj fjord.karve.experiment.server/fjord.karve.experiment.server/
COPY /Users/dan/Projects/Fjord/fjord.karve.experiment.server/fjord.karve.experiment.server/nuget.config fjord.karve.experiment.server/fjord.karve.experiment.server/
COPY Fjord.Domain/Fjord.Domain.csproj Fjord.Domain/
COPY Fjord.Karve.Command/Fjord.Karve.Command.csproj Fjord.Karve.Command/
COPY fjord.karve.experiment.server/DAL/Fjord.DAL.csproj fjord.karve.experiment.server/DAL/
COPY /Users/dev/Projects/Fjord/fjord.karve.experiment.server/DAL/nuget.config fjord.karve.experiment.server/DAL/
COPY Fjord.Karve.Query/Fjord.Karve.Query.csproj Fjord.Karve.Query/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/fjord.karve.experiment.server/fjord.karve.experiment.server
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs 

    dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Fjord.Karve.experiment.Server.dll"]
```

I should probably mention that I attempted to get back to the drawing board a few minutes early with the following commands. Which may have caused some kind of unexpected issues.

```
docker images
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format) says that the first `FROM` may only be preceded by `ARG` instructions.